# (How) can I return the most specific row on a join?

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to work out a query that can parse through a table of prices (and exceptions to those prices) to yield the applicable price for a product, ideally using a join. I'm on PostgreSQL. For example, consider a teddy bear store. The default teddy bear price is $20. If, however, the teddy bear is at least 12 inches tall, we want to charge $30. If the teddy bear is made of suede, we charge $40, and if the teddy bear is both at least 12 inches tall and made of suede, we charge $60 (because the larger bear also requires more of the expensive fabric). ***ETA:*** We now also have a grass bear special because we just hired a teddy bear maker who was previously a florist. Given the perishable nature of the bear, it costs $15 if it's at least 24 inches tall.

Here's what the `prices` table I have looks like (sorry about the formatting):

***EDITED:*** I added the grass bear to better reflect my inability to make any assumptions about the data. I simply need to pick the price that best corresponds to each product without knowledge of how different features affect the price, positively or negatively.

```
  price | min_ht | fabric 
---------------------------
| 20    | NULL   | NULL   |
---------------------------
| 30    | 12     | NULL   |
---------------------------
| 40    | NULL   | suede  |
---------------------------
| 60    | 12     | suede  |
---------------------------
| 15    | 24     | grass  | <-- our floral special
---------------------------
```

which I want to join with a `products` table like

```
  id    | height | fabric
---------------------------
| 1     | 8      | cotton |
---------------------------
| 2     | 6      | poly   |
---------------------------
| 3     | 4      | suede  |
---------------------------
| 4     | 18     | cotton |
---------------------------
| 5     | 12     | suede  |
---------------------------
| 6     | 30     | grass  |
---------------------------
```

to yield

```
  id    | height | fabric | price 
-----------------------------------
| 1     | 8      | cotton | 20    |
-----------------------------------
| 2     | 6      | poly   | 20    |
-----------------------------------
| 3     | 4      | suede  | 40    |
-----------------------------------
| 4     | 18     | cotton | 30    |
-----------------------------------
| 5     | 12     | suede  | 60    |
-----------------------------------
| 6     | 30     | grass  | 15    |
-----------------------------------
```

Any ideas? I saw a [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/mysql-most-specific-to-least-specific), though it is unfortunately both unanswered and regarding MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes some assumptions but it will do:

```
SELECT
    prd.id, prd.height, prd.fabric,
    MAX(pri.price) AS price
FROM
    products AS prd
  JOIN
    prices AS pri
      ON  (prd.height >= pri.min_ht OR pri.min_ht IS NULL)
      AND (prd.fabric =  pri.fabric OR pri.fabric IS NULL) 
GROUP BY
    prd.id ;
```

The above assumes that the more details a pricing has, the higher the price is. Since that is not the case, a different, more general approach:

```
SELECT
    prd.id, prd.height, prd.fabric,
    pri.price
FROM
    products AS prd
  , LATERAL
    ( SELECT p.price
      FROM prices AS p
      WHERE (prd.height > p.min_ht OR p.min_ht IS NULL)
        AND (prd.fabric = p.fabric OR p.fabric IS NULL) 
      ORDER BY
          ((p.min_ht IS NOT NULL)::int + (p.fabric IS NOT NULL)::int) DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS pri ;
```

Tested at [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/96baf/14)

Comment: It could be written with some window functions (or DISTINCT ON) in previous versions. That's why I asked for your version.